# Django sort by annotate in model Meta

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a way to set ordering in a models Meta class by an annotated field?

i.e.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class ModelB(models.Model):
    name    = models.CharField()
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA)
```

This is what i can do for queryset but need same way to do on class Meta if possible

```
ModalA.objects.all()
      .annotate(
          count_b=Count("modal_a")
      )
      .order_by("count_b")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override the `.objects` manager to the soring, so:

```
class ModelAManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).annotate(
            count_b = Count('modelb')
        ).order_by('count_b')
```

and then register this as the manager of `ModelA`:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    # …
    objects = ModelAManager()
```

That being said, I would order by the count in the views where you need this, and not in general, here you make a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, but it means that if you make extra joins through filtering, annotating, etc. the two (or more) `JOIN`s will interact with each other, and thus act as a multiplier to the other `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s.

It thus might be better to simply order by the number of related `ModelB`s when necessary.

We can also add a method to the `Queryset` that makes it possible to do the ordering by `count_b` through a method:

```
class ModelAQueryset(models.QuerySet):
    def order_by_b(self):
        return self.annotate(
            count_b=Count('modelb')
        ).order_by('count_b')
```

then we define a manager based on the `ModelAQueryset`:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    # …
    objects = ModelAQueryset.as_manager()
```

then you can order on `b` with:

```
ModelA.objects.order_by_b()
```

You thus can call `.order_by_b()` in the queryset at any part in the chain where you construct the queryset.

Comment: Or perhaps a method on the queryset to add that annotation and order instead of overriding `get_queryset` on the manager.

Comment: The issue is I am using a call based datatable and it seems to ignore the ordering on the queryset itself. I can set the ordering field on the datatable class though so maybe that can work and make more sense...

Comment: @Spirconi: this looks like the *x-y* problem: you want to solve *x* and you do that by *y*, and you thus ask a question about *y*, but the real problem is *x*. Therefore I think it might be better to ask a new question where you explain the real problem that you are facing.

Comment: Yes, both of your suggested solutions work based on the question I actually asked. So I marked as solution. Unfortunately the Datatable class still ignores it even though I can see it has worked based on queryset data.